# Where to find NodeRed documentation for nodes

Tags: node-red

I have exported a flow from node red, but I don't know what the JSON means:

```
{'crontab': '',
 'id': 'b7a9e74f.11dd78',
 'name': '',
 'once': True,
 'onceDelay': '1',
 'payload': '1',
 'payloadType': 'num',
 'props': [{'p': 'payload'}],
 'repeat': '1',
 'topic': '',
 'type': 'inject',
 'wires': [['cb98937a.362e7']],
 'x': 100,
 'y': 120,
 'z': 'c74b6284.bc6ce'}
```

I see documenation here:

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/nodes

But it doesn't document what all of the keys mean, such as 'once', 'onceDelay', etc.

Does anyone know where I can find that information?  I have been searching online for about an hour, mostly on the nodered site, with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you don't.

Slightly longer answer:

The JSON representation is not really meant to be user facing, what the value get mapped to will only be recorded in the source code of the node in question.

The only values that are fixed are:

- `x`,`y` location on the canvas
- `z` the id of the tab the node is on
- `id` a unique id for the instance of the node
- `type` the type of node
- `wires` a 2d array of other node `id` values that this node is wired to. First dimension is output port.

Comment: Is it not meant to be user facing because users are expected to use the GUI to create the nodes?

Comment: Yes the normal approach is to use the GUI, if you want to automate flow creation the you really need to have a full understanding of each node you want to use because values can be generated/modified at creation time by the HTML/Config dialog of the node in question.

Comment: I want a full understanding of each node.  Unfortunately, it sounds like you're saying that there is no documentation, so the only way to gain an understanding of each node is to inspect the source code.

Comment: I'm saying that any documentation would have to be part of each node, and I think it's fair to say that there hasn't been a huge demand for it so far and those that have needed it have reverse engineered from the nodes they are using.